# how is td auto resized in this case?

Tags: css, autoresize, html-table

```
<body>
<table width="100%">
<tr>
<td><div>content1 goes here</div></td>
<td><div>content2 goes here</div></td>
<td><div>content3 goes here</div></td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
```

The content(1,2,3) can include other html tags.
There is no setting on the width of td,then how on earth is it autoresized?
I've now somehow triggered an unexpected autoresize.

Comment: Could you explain more about the autoresize that is happening? What behavior do you want?

Answer (score 2):

The autoresize is part of the way the browsers handle tables. It doesn't matter if you add a width or not.
This will give you a deeper explanation:
http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/tables.html#model

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want the td to resize then put a ***width on the div*** tag inside the td and make its ***overflow to hidden or ellipsis*** and show text ***innertext as a tool tip*** to the div.